# Compact form of solution of $\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(1+\alpha^n\sin(x)^{2n}\right)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, summation, hyperbolic-functions

I hope it won't be categorized as a trivial question, I solved this integral and arrived at the following form:
$${\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(1+\alpha^n\sin(x)^{2n}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{n\pi}{2}\ln\left(\frac{\alpha}{4}\right)+\pi\sum_{k=1}^{n}\text{acosh}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\alpha}\left(\alpha+\sqrt{\alpha^2-2\cos\left(\frac{2k-1}{n}\pi\right)\alpha+1}+1\right)}\right)}$$
But it seems a bit long and too "complicated" (nested roots and hyperbolic inverse functions)

---

Would anyone be able to manipulate this solution to arrive at a more compact form?
I "played" around with it a bit and came to this form:
$${\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\ln\left(1+\alpha^n\sin(x)^{2n}\right)\mathrm{d}x=\pi\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{z_k+1+\alpha}+\sqrt{z_k+1-\alpha}}{2\sqrt{2}}\right)\qquad\text{where }z_k:=\sqrt{\alpha^{2}-2\cos\left(\frac{2k-1}{n}\pi\right)\alpha+1}}$$

For $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Which however is just as long (technically has 2 nested radicals).
(Mainly I would like to remove those nested radicals, then the type of functions you use is indifferent, as long as it is a little more compact)

Comment: Is there a reason you expect a more compact form to exist? What purpose do you need a simplification for, if it is not purely an exercise in aesthetics? (Not saying that it wouldn't be worth it if that were the case, but if you need simplifications for a specific calculation those kinds of answers would be more useful to you)

Comment: @NinadMunshi No, I don't know if there is a more compact form. I wanted to find a more compact form only because I'm writing the results of integrals of this type in LaTeX (integrals in which the solution involves the summation of components of complex numbers: real, imaginary, absolute value or argument). Only that this result slips a bit from the column in which I write them and I wanted to try to shorten it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi For example there is an integral analogous to this in which there is the tangent instead of the sine which is much shorter.

Comment: Any restriction for $\alpha$ ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$. A flaw of the "hyperbolic arccosine form" it's the fact that you have to consider $\alpha>0$, because in the form with $z_k$ it becomes again $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$

Comment: If $0<\alpha<1$, I suppose that the result is a generalized hypergeometric function (numerically verified)

Comment: @MathAttack Would you like to show how you solve this integral?

Comment: @LuckyChouhan it's a little long, practically you start by differentiating with respect to $\alpha$, then you integrate by changing the variable and impose $\sin(x)^2=s$, you get a completely polynomial stuff that can be solved with the residuals. Later when you get to the result you integrate again with respect to $\alpha$ and add a constant that I don't remember now (like $\ln(4^n)$, I don't remember now)

Comment: @LuckyChouhan I did all calculus here: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uohthbcpcq?lang=it

There are a couple of errors every now and then that I haven't corrected because it was temporary stuff anyway (like line 8 is not $1/x$ but $\ln(x)$). It's in those accounts I considered $\alpha^n=x$, so a few things are different. Normally I use desmos to do these accounts because I have immediate confirmation of the accuracy of the accounts

Comment: @MathAttack Thank you for telling in detail and sharing that desmos link! Btw I have never done stuff like in line 21 even with pen and paper..

Comment: There is a "simple" solution in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions (nice and simple patterns).

Comment: İ dont think we can get a completely polynomial staff by the substitution $\sin^2x=s$.

Comment: @BobDobbs Watch the comment of August 25th at 16:35, I left the link for Desmos with all the calculations. (However solving the integral is not what we are talking about in the question)

Answer (score -1):

In terms of generalized hypergeometric functions
$$I_n=\displaystyle\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\log\big(1+\alpha^n\sin(x)^{2n}\big)\,dx$$ for $n>1$
$$\large\color{blue}{I_n=\pi\, \frac{a_n}{b_n}\,\alpha^n\,J_n}$$ Coefficients $a_n$
$$\{16,32,256,512,2048,4096,65536\}$$

form sequence $A101926$ (with an offset of $2$).

Coefficients $b_n$
$$\{3,5,35,63,231,429,6435\}$$   form sequence $A001790$ (with an offset of $2$).

Concerning the $J_n$, the pattern is very clear
$$J_2=\, _4F_3\left(1,1,\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2},2,2;-\alpha ^2\right)$$
$$J_3=\,
   _5F_4\left(1,1,\frac{7}{6},\frac{9}{6},\frac{11}{6};\frac{4}{3},\frac{5}{3},2,2;-\alpha ^3\right)$$
$$J_4=\,
   _6F_5\left(1,1,\frac{9}{8},\frac{11}{8},\frac{13}{8},\frac{15}{8};\frac{5}{4},
   \frac{6}{4},\frac{7}{4},2,2;-\alpha ^4\right)$$
$$J_5=\,
   _7F_6\left(1,1,\frac{11}{10},\frac{13}{10},\frac{15}{10},\frac{17}{10},\frac{19}{
   10};\frac{6}{5},\frac{7}{5},\frac{8}{5},\frac{9}{5},2,2;-\alpha ^5\right)$$
$$J_6=\,
   _8F_7\left(1,1,\frac{13}{12},\frac{15}{12},\frac{17}{12},\frac{19}{12},\frac{21}{12
   },\frac{23}{12};\frac{7}{6},\frac{8}{6},\frac{9}{6},\frac{10}{6},\frac{11}{6},2,2;-\alpha ^6\right)$$